# Set logged in user without spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm not a big fan of `Spring Security`, I think it's too overrated. So i'm trying to use alternatives to secure my `rest API`, and one of them which I like is [Spring sandwich](http://springsandwich.com) which based on interceptors.

The only issue i have though is that I want smth similar to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`
so I don't have to pass the user every time but more of a global object.

Anybody has any idea how to do that?

ps: i'm using `spring boot`

Comment: if i understood you may try to save user in the session and pass it throw the whole needed rest points..

Comment: any example on how to do that?

Comment: So instead of going with a well supported and tested library you want to roll your own? The interceptors do the same as spring security. Nonetheless you could write an interceptor that populates a thread local and retrieve it from there each time you need it. Take care of also clearing the thread local else you leak information to other threads!

Comment: When you are sure enough your user is authenticated, you can set it using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);`

Comment: @Afridi this only works with spring security, already mentioned that

Comment: Then you can use thread local variables to make it globally static data across the project

Answer (score 0):

Although I highly suggest reconsidering Spring Security, you can also use HttpSession as an alternative.

When an user logs in, you can store your 'User' object in his session like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(HttpSession session, @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
    // check if user has right credentials ...
    session.setAttribute("USER", user);
    return "You have logged in successfully"; // you can also redirect instead, do as you wish
}
```

and then you can access the User object like so:

```
User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
```

you can also get the session from `HttpServletRequest` (`request.getSession()`)

Alternatively, if you can't pass the object HttpSession to your controller for some reason, you can also autowire the session like so:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpSession session;
```

See [Spring Session](https://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) for more details